# How to write this condition in sql?

Tags: c#, sql, conditional-statements

I have one problem. I want to write this condition in sql:

```
AnyString.StartsWith(String1 + "_" + String2) or AnyString.StartsWith(String2 + "_" + String1)
```

For example I want to make a function:

```
string commandString = "UPDATE [AnyTable] Set [AnyColumn]='Something' WHERE and here the condition above";
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Update Table_A
set Column_B = 'WhatEver'
where column_C like String1 + '[_]' + String2 +'%' 
or column_C like String2 + '[_]' + String1 +'%'
```

Comment: Use the parameters for prevent the sqli

Comment: i didn't quite put the string handling correctly with the quotes (i lazily just copied your strings above)

Comment: i feel better now, i cleaned up my strings

Comment: This will match strings separated by characters other than underscore, because `_` in `LIKE` matches any character. You need to escape it in order for the query to function properly.

Comment: you are totally correct!  I so rarely use anything outside of %, that i didn't even think about it!  Good Catch!

Answer (score 5):

The select:

```
Select *
From Table1
Where Field1 Like string1 + '[_]' + string2 + '%'
Or Field1 Like string2 + '[_]' + string1 + '%'
```

The update:

```
Update Table1
Set Field2 = 'YourValue'
Where Field1 Like string1 + '[_]' + string2 + '%'
Or Field1 Like string2 + '[_]' + string1 + '%'
```

Comment: This will match strings separated by characters other than underscore, because `_` in `LIKE` matches any character. You need to escape it in order for the query to function properly.

Answer (score 1):

`select * from Foo where Bar LIKE 'string%'`

(where the % is a wildcard meaning match anything)

Comment: % on the end for a StartsWith equivalent

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
"UPDATE [AnyTable] Set [AnyColumn]='Something' WHERE first_col LIKE 
sometext_othertext% OR second_col LIKE sometext_othertext%"
```

Using % you can select a text sentence which starts with the next word.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx (SQL LIKE)

Answer (score 0):

```
string commandString = "UPDATE [AnyTable] 
Set [AnyColumn]='Something' 
WHERE AnyString like String1 + "_" + String2 + "%" or AnyString like String2 + "_" + String1 + "%";
```